# Global Import/using Aliasing in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, namespaces, global, alias

Using import aliasing in one file/class, we can reference class library namespaces by assigning our own custom alias like this:

```
' VB
Imports Db = Company.Lib.Data.Objects 

// C#
using Db = Company.Lib.Data.Objects;
```

And then we are able to reference the classes inside of `Company.Lib.Data.Objects` by using the `Db` alias that we assigned.

Is it possible to do this at the global level so that the alias is applied to the entire solution instead of just one file/class?

Currently, we are working with web applications, so I was hoping we could add something to web.config, but I am also interested in whether or not this is possible with windows forms, console apps, and/or class libraries.

Comment: In case you are wondering, the class library in question has some ambiguous naming of classes, and this has cause some annoyances to us.  So, we essentially want to split it up into three sections by using Import aliasing.  And we want to do it at the global level, as opposed to adding this to every file.  If there is a better way, I am all ears!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes this is a supported scenario in VB.Net projects.  The way to do this is the following

- Right Click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Properties
- Go to the References tab
- In the "Imported Namespaces" field type "Db=Company.Lib.Data.Objects"
- Hit "Add User Import"

This will set up the alias for all files in the project.

This however does not work in C# projects.  C# as a language doesn't have the concept of a global using/import.  Instead it only supports them at the file level.

Comment: Awesome!  We use VB.NET exclusively (dont laugh!), so that is fine.  But, does this work in "Web Sites" or only "Projects"?

Comment: @Josh most of my job involves working on the VB.Net IDE so no laughing here.  This will only work though on web applications.  I do not believe it will work for web sites as they don't have the notion of a global build.

Comment: We really love using VB.NET here, so keep up the great work!  Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In  your web.config file for your website - or most likely app.config file for a project (not confirmed)

```
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
        <namespaces>
            <clear/>
            <add namespace="System"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
            <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
```

anything that you put in this section should be a valid replacement for the Imports clause on the top of your code behind pages. Worked wonders for me, let me know if it helps you out

Comment: But I need aliasing... question has already been answered but thanks anyway

Comment: @JoshStodola Incidentally, I did some testing and this technique can work with aliases — _vis-à-vis_: `<add namespace="ColUtil = Org.Utils.CollectionUtils"/>`.

Comment: Does this work in C# as well? I'll have to try it out!

Comment: @Adam, I did not try it yet.

Comment: This is typical, no context for <pages> element: <configuration><system.web><pages>