# VB.NET equivalent to C#'s using directive

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am converting some code from C# to VB.NET, and I need to know what the equivalent is for C#'s using directive.

**Update:** Sorry, but so far I haven't gotten my answer. Here is a C# example:

```
using moOutlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using moExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ReportGen
{
    class Reports
```

Comment: It is the using *directive* not the using *statement*.

Comment: This is why almost every question should include a code snippet :-)

Comment: ... and why you should take care with terminology. The more precise you are with your question, the more likely you are to get the relevant answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet but, in fairness, if the OP knew the nuance of directive vs statement, they probably knew how to locate the answer themselves.

Comment: If you like me you ended up here looking for the statement ie using (var obj = new obj) { } equivalent the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887831/how-does-the-using-statement-translate-from-c-sharp-to-vb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the [Imports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement. Place any import statements that you need at the very top of your code file, just like the `using` directive in C#:

```vb
Imports moOutlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Imports moExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Namespace ReportGen
   Public Class Reports
      'Your code here
   End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a link showing a syntax comparison between C# and VB.NET side by side.

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

From the link:

```
Using reader As StreamReader = File.OpenText("test.txt")
  Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
  While Not line Is Nothing
    Console.WriteLine(line)
    line = reader.ReadLine()
  End While
End Using
```

Or the imports statement (from site also):

```
Imports System 

Namespace Hello
   Class HelloWorld 
      Overloads Shared Sub Main(ByVal args() As String) 
         Dim name As String = "VB.NET" 

         'See if an argument was passed from the command line
          If args.Length = 1 Then name = args(0) 

          Console.WriteLine("Hello, " & name & "!") 
      End Sub 
   End Class 
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Imports moOutlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; 
Imports moExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

see: [Global Import/using Aliasing in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480290/global-import-using-aliasing-in-net)

Answer (score -1):

"Using" with a capital U